# I want to compare 2 files in AIX and print the difference in numbers

Tags: aix

I want to compare 2 files, for example `file1` and `file2`, 
and in the output I have to print the differences as well as how many lines were added and/or deleted.

### File 1

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
```

### file 2

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
grape1
grape2
grape3
mango4
```

### output should be:

```
No of newly added list= 4
No of lines removed =0
Difference =4 

Newely Added list 
------------

grape1
grape2
grape3
mango4

Removed list 
--------
None
```

Comment: What work have you done so far to attempt to solve this?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and show us what you have so far and which part of this is giving you trouble.

Comment: i have tried diff command to print the difference , but unable to print the No of newly added list number and number of names removed from the file .

Comment: Does this need to work in both AIX and Linux? Curious why both OS's are tagged.

Comment: yes . We have both OS

Comment: Your title says "AIX", so if this really needs to be cross-platform, that should be made clear -- AIX tools often differ enough to make a difference.

Comment: kindly help for AIX OS ..

Comment: Thanks . .  with out giving argument i need the output .. is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need that exact output format, you could use `diff` and `diffstat`.

e.g.

```
$ diff file1 file2 | diffstat -s
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
```

If, say, `apple4` was deleted from `file2`, the output would look like this:

```
$ diff file1 file2 | diffstat -s
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

If you do need that exact output, you could use `diff` alone in a script like this:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

if [ ! "$#" -eq 2 ] ; then
  echo "Exactly two file arguments are required."
  exit 1
fi

f1="$1"
f2="$2"    

# sort and uniq the input files before diffing.
# if you have `mktemp`, use this:
t1=$(mktemp)
t2=$(mktemp)
# else kludge it with something like this:
# mkdir ~/tmp
# t1="~/tmp/$f1.tmp"
# t2="~/tmp/$f2.tmp"

# if your `sort` has a `-u` option for `uniq` (e.g. GNU sort), you
# can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`
sort "$f1" | uniq > "$t1"
sort "$f2" | uniq > "$t2"

add=$(diff "$t1" "$t2" | grep -c '^> ')
del=$(diff "$t1" "$t2" | grep -c '^< ')

[ -z "$add" ] && add=0
[ -z "$del" ] && del=0

diff=$(( add - del ))

cat <<__EOF__
No of newly added list= $add
No of lines removed = $del
Difference = $diff

Newly Added list 
------------
__EOF__

if [ "$add" -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo None.
else
  diff "$t1" "$t2" | sed -n -e 's/^> //p'
fi

cat <<__EOF__

Removed list 
--------
__EOF__

if [ "$del" -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo None.
else
  diff "$t1" "$t2" | sed -n -e 's/^< //p'
fi

rm -f "$t1" "$t2"
```

If your `grep` doesn't have a `-c` option, use `diff ... | grep ... | wc -l`

You could use `bc` or `dc` or something to do the calculation if your `sh` doesn't have built-in integer arithmetic.  I can't recall any that don't but commercial unixes can have some really primitive and ancient implementations of common tools.  The script was tested with `dash` so should work with any current POSIX shell.

Output:

```
$ ./keerthana.sh file1 file2
No of newly added list = 4
No of lines removed = 0
Difference = 4

Newly Added list 
------------
grape1
grape2
grape3
mango4

Removed list 
--------
None.
```

Comment: OP specified AIX, which implies using the tools normally on *that* platform.  If it weren't constrained, others would have quickly answered this.

Comment: 1. they might have, but they didn't.  2.  Answers aren't only for the OP, they're for anyone with similar questions - to me, this is only an interesting question because it offered the opportunity to teach a generic technique, a method of embedding output from tools into a fixed format.  3.  It's not unreasonable to install additional tools you need to do a job.  neither `diff` nor `diffstat` are hard to find - OP already mentioned he has diff.

Comment: @ThomasDickey and 4. it wasn't hard to modify to use only `diff`.

Comment: Without parsing arugument , shall we print the output , like declaring file1 and file2  within the script

Comment: easily done, just comment out the check for number of args, and set `f1='file1'` and `f2='file2'` in the script rather than `f1="$1"` and `f2="$2"`.  Or if you want to accept args but have defaults if they're not provided, use `f1="${1:-file1}"` and `f2="${2:-file2}"`

Comment: glad to hear it.  btw, upvoting and/or accepting an answer (by clicking on the tick mark to the left) is [how we say thanks on stackexchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)